# How can I use my personal Google Drive to store user files, in my Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, file-upload, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm working on a flutter app and I was wondering if it was possible to store user files (such as an avatar image) on a specific file in my personal Google Drive. I have already setup an image picker and I get a Xfile from it.

I tried using the Google Drive API, but I stumbled upon a lot of tutorials and guides showing how the user can save files inside their own google drive, but that is not what I'm trying to do !

I need to log in to my personal google drive, with my google cloud service account, and upload the file, all in background without the user noticing.

So even with this difficulty to find proper documentation, I tried numerous times but still get errors like:
" Unhandled Exception: Failed to obtain access credentials. Error: invalid_grant Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in a reasonable timeframe. Check your iat and exp values in the JWT claim. Status code: 400 "

Comment: You don't want users to be able to upload files to your _personal_ Google Drive Account. It takes only one troll to upload something compromising and your account can get potentially banned.

Comment: Thank you very much for your concern. My app is closed, not opened to the public. I have very few users and I will setup a special google account just for my client. Now do you have any idea that could help me in my research ? Best regards ;-)